# android jelly bean doesn't support target-densityDpi

Tags: android, meta-tags, viewport, dpi, android-4.2-jelly-bean

since jelly Bean, i have problems with my webapp and the render of the viewport in the webview.

Usually i use the meta viewport with this parameters to fix my content and have a good design :

```
name="viewport" content=" width=device-width; 
                initial-scale=1.0; 
                maximum-scale=1.0; 
                user-scalable=no;
                target-densityDpi=device-dpi;
```

But with Jelly Bean, the property "target-densityDpi" seems to be not supported or ignored.
On a galaxy nexus (720px*1280, device pixel ratio to 2), the window width size is 360px
And on galaxy nexus S (480*800, device pixel ratio to 1.5), the window width size is 360px.

I don't found on the Android developper's website any help or info about this subject.

So, target-density is really ignored ??
A trick can force the deviceDPi ?
Or we are forced to work with the medium-density screen, by default ??

If anyone have a solution ?
Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the problem might be in the use of semicolons. Change the semicolons to regular commas and remove the last semicolon.

I use the following viewport metatag in my app and it works correctly in Jelly Bean.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same thing on the latest Chrome for Android using this jQuery:

```
<meta content='user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, width=device-width' id='viewport' name='viewport'>

var viewPortScale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;

$('#viewport').attr('content', 'user-scalable=no, initial-scale='+viewPortScale+', width=device-width');
```

This sets the initial-scale viewport meta tag setting to the correct scale for 1 CSS Pixel == 1 Device Pixel.

You can't use 'width='+screen.width because screen.width doesn't return the physical pixel dimensions. I tried using http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/ on my Nexus 7 in Chrome and all the numbers are viewport pixels.